# Creating join table vs manually defining?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The app I am working on is a print shop that prints items and each item can have multiple locations with each location having it's own pricing to add onto the final cost of the item.

I'm doing something like this in the create method:

```
if (@product.front_print && @product.back_print).present?
   @product.production_price = (@product.price.to_i + 5)
else
   @product.production_price = @product.price
end
```

`price` is base price.  `production_price` is final cost of goods.

This is an example where if there is more than one print location (ie, front + back), it will generate $5 extra on top of the base price to the final production_price.

The final situation will have 6 possible print locations.

Should i be creating a join table for something like this with the join table having a Product model, and PrintLocation model?

The PrintLocation model would have ID, Title, and Price.

Is this ideal or what would be the best route to go about doing this?

Comment: `(@product.front_print && @product.back_print).present?` will not work as you expect, this will evaluate as `@product.back_print.present?` since the `&&` collapses them to a singular value. What you want is `[ @product.front_print, @product.back_print ].all?(&:present?)`

Comment: Make a table that defines the locations and the associated costs for each location. Each order can join through to that via a join table. A many-to-many relationship. `has_many` and `has_many ... through: ...`

Comment: I definitely need to create 2 new tables, one for PrintLocation and one for PrintPrice.  And then would i then have those 2 with a join table to Product? PrintPrice will define the price of PrintLocation... Now would i be doing something like? print_location.rb `belongs_to :product, has_one :print_price`, print_price.rb `belongs_to :print_location`  or how would i be formatting the :thorough association

Comment: Hows this? https://sketch.io/render/sk-af473c6df0b96cd0f17452e4f69e7e83.jpeg

Comment: Try and describe code in code, not as pictures. We can't edit pictures to make minor improvements, nor test them in an editor.

Comment: You may want to sketch something out in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) or actual Ruby code. If you're really not sure where to go,  try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).